# Issue in checkstyle configuration in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

My objective is to implement Google's Java Style Checkstyle as stated in https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn-history/r130/trunk/javaguide.html .

In IntelliJ I have enabled Checkstyle plugin and try to point checkstyle xml (downloaded from https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml).

I got following exception:

```
Property 'fileExtensions' in module Checker does not exist
```

although this property is defined in the xml as

```xml
<property name="fileExtensions" value="java, properties, xml"/>
```

Exception details:

```
org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.exception.CheckStylePluginException:
The CheckStyle rules file could not be loaded.
Property 'fileExtensions' in module Checker does not exist, please check the documentation
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.blacklistAndShowMessage(CheckerFactory.java:248)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.createChecker(CheckerFactory.java:202)
```

Comment: The maven checkstyle plugin also gives the same error. Maven plugin Internally by default its refers version 6.1.1. To use the latest checkstyle version in that plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html .

Answer (score 17):

You have run into a version problem. At the time of this writing, the IntelliJ plugin for Checkstyle is still on version 6.1.1, because IntelliJ still runs under Java 6 on MacOS. Checkstyle 6.1.1 is the last Checkstyle version that still used Java 6.

The `fileExtensions` property was introduced in Checkstyle 6.3. The *google_checks.xml* of today also makes use of the *EmptyCatchBlock* check, which was introduced in Checkstyle 6.5.

So, in order to use the Google checks today in IntelliJ, you must use the Checkstyle 6.1.1 based version of *google_checks.xml*, which may be found [here](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-6.1.1/google_checks.xml).

Comment: google_checks.xml was added to JAR from http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.2
, google_checks.xml was introduced at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.0 , so for 6.0 release it is - https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/a780f92fe771d1c062408633eb06453e674b2f2e/google_checks.xml

Comment: Thanks Roman. I think OP needs 6.1.1; updated my answer accordingly.